# Meteor Java Script startup

Tags: javascript, meteor

It seems that in Meteor I don't need to have an `index.html` file to have a working page. Must I create an start-up template or JavaScript file then?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to take a quick look at the `Meteor` Todo app tutorial, that should answer your question.
It is fairly quick to go through it and should answer your question :)

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app